# TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Fields' from assembly 'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

Tags: sitecore-commerce

Applying Sitecore Experience Commerce 9.0 Update-3 on top of a fresh Update-2 (on Sitecore 9.0.2) installation results in this exception, after performing step "6.5. Republish and rebuild the search indexes", in the upgrade guide:

> [TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Fields' from assembly
>   'Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc, Version=3.7.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.]
>   Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Providers.RenderingViewProvider.GetCustomViewPath(IRendering
>   rendering) +0
>   Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.Common.Providers.RenderingViewProvider.Resolve(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IRendering rendering, String viewName) +240
>   Sitecore.Commerce.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata.Controllers.MetadataController.Index()
>   +34    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +90    System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +35
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.b__12()
>   +80    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +454
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +454
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName) +524

Inspecting all the related dlls with `dotPeek`, I see this:

```
protected virtual string GetCustomViewPath(IRendering rendering)
{
  string str = (string) null;
  Item settingsItem = this.MultisiteContext.GetSettingsItem(rendering.Item);
  if (settingsItem != null)
    str = settingsItem[Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Templates.**Settings.Fields**.get_CustomRenderingViewPath()];
  return str;
}
```

Settings doesn't seem to exist, and therefore Fields does not exist.  I cannot find any property called `CustomRenderingViewPath` anywhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a missed step.  The documentation isn't very clear about it, but you must update to Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.8 to get version 3.8.0.0 of the required dlls.